# How to mark check box state Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am working in `Roles and Permission`.

I have fetched all permission from `permissions` table. I want to show  all available permission to superadmin and at the same time if he has already that some permission then checkbox should be checked ,if some are not, checkbox should not checked for them

`Permisson` table has field:`id,name,display_name,description,timestamp`

`roles` table:`id,name,display_name,description,timestamp`

`permission_user` table:`permission_id,user_id`

Here is current state :https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O8AA.jpg

Rolecontroller:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $role = Role::where('id', $id)->with('permissions')->first();
        $permissions = Permission::all();

     //   dd($role);//i am getting permission of that role
        return view('manage.roles.edit')->with('permissions',$permissions)-   >with('role',$role);
    }
```

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

         <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Edit</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
               form...
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Edit</div>

                <div class="panel-body">


     @foreach( $permissions as $permission )
<p>
<input type="checkbox" 
name="permissions[]" 
id="perm_{{ $permission->id }}" 
{{ in_array($permission->id, $role->permissions->pluck('id') ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} 
value="{{ $permission->id }}">

{{ $permission->display_name }}
</p>
@endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Here is your problem: `id="{{$role->display_name?'checked="checked"':''}}"` This goes into the `id` attribute, and not into the `checked` as you want.

Comment: updated: @foreach($permissions as $permission)
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="" id="{{$role->display_name?'checked="checked"':''}}">
                
                {{$permission->display_name}}
                </p>
                @endforeach

Comment: Don't add images, update the question with the relevant code

Comment: i have  updated view

Comment: I don't see any change there. You still don't have the `checked` attribute in your code.

Comment: i did this got all checked :still error <input type="checkbox" name="" checked="{{$role->display_name?'checked="checked"':''}}">

Comment: The `checked` attribute should appear **only** if you want the input to be checked, but it is not relevant for the `id` that you have there.

Comment: @David What code would you normally use to check if a user has any given permission?

Comment: @milo526  $role = Role::where('id', $id)->with('permissions')->first(); it check if that role has permission

Comment: @David that check is a role has a permission, not if a user has a permission as I requested.

Comment: i want to check how many permission this Role has

Comment: @David with your edit your whole post changed. Please only use edits to supply extra information or make the question easier to read, not to edit the scope of the question!

Comment: Hello,thanks i have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
{{$role->display_name?'checked="checked"':''}}"
```

To

```
{{$role->display_name }}" {{Auth::user()->can($permission) ?'checked="checked"':''}}>
```

This will give you the following code snippet

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="{{$role->display_name }}" {{Auth::user()->can($permission) ?'checked="checked"':''}}>
  {{$permission->display_name}}
</p>
```

This will set the id to the display name and use a coalesce operator to check if the current authenticated user (or whatever user you change that to) has the role `$role`.

Comment: code updated got error:in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\manage\roles\edit.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

The code from @Milo should work, but my guess is it's not working because it isn't connected to users..

Instead of Auth::user()->can($permission), try to make a method on the role model that returns a Boolean if the role contains that permission parameter. Something like $role->contains($permission).

Then do something like list the id and name(careful not to put checked in them), then afterwards, I usually do something like @if($role->contains($permission)) checked="checked" @endif

Answer (score 0):

First create method to check is the permission already add in role model

```
public function isPermissionExist($id)
{
foreach($this->permissions as $permission){
if($permission->id == $id)
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

next in view

```
@foreach( $permissions as $permission )
<p>
<input type="checkbox" 
name="permissions[]" 
id="perm_{{ $permission->id }}" 
@if($role->isPermissionExist($permission->id)) checked @endif 
value="{{ $permission->id }}">
{{ $permission->display_name }}
</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your edit.blade.php

```
<label class="checkbox-inline "for="perm[{{ $permission->id }}]">
      <input id="perm[{{ $permission->id }}]" name="perm[{{ $permission->id }}]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $permission->id }}"
       @if($role->permissions->contains($permission->id)) checked=checked @endif
       > {{ $permission->name }}
 </label>
```